# `defaultValue` and `onChange` prevents state changes from updating render

Tags: reactjs

I have a multi-tabbed panel that changes a textarea based on the combination of tabs selected. In order for changes in this panel to provide automatic updates, I've provided an `onChange` listener but this is causing issues with the `defaultValue` setting and not changing the contents of the `textarea` when the state changes.

```js
const props = {
 'x': {
   'label': {
     'text': 'Ex'
    }
  },
  'y': {
   'label': {
     'text': 'Why'
    }
  }
}

class TodoApp extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
   super(props);
    this.state = {
     tab: 'x',
      subtab: 'One'
    }
  }
  
  getActiveTab(tab) {
   if (this.state.tab === tab) return ' active';
    else return '';
  }
  
  getActiveSubTab(subtab) {
   if (this.state.subtab === subtab) return ' active';
    else return '';
  }
  
  getOneTab() {
   return(
     <div className="tab-pane active fade in">
        <textarea cols="16" rows="5" 
          defaultValue={"1. " + props[this.state.tab].label.text} 
          onChange={(e) => {console.log(e)}}></textarea>
      </div>
    );
  }
  
  getContent() {
   if (this.state.subtab === 'One') {
     return this.getOneTab();
    } else {
    
    }
  }
  
 render() {
   return (
     <div>
       <ul className="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
         <li className={"tabProperties" + this.getActiveTab('x')}>
           <a onClick={() => this.setState({tab: 'x'})} role="tab">X</a>
         </li>
          <li className={"tabProperties" + this.getActiveTab('y')}>
            <a onClick={() => this.setState({tab: 'y'})} role="tab">Y</a>
          </li>
       </ul>
        <div className="tab-content">
          <ul className="tabProperties nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
            <li className={"tabProperties" + this.getActiveSubTab('One')}>
              <a onClick={() => this.setState({subtab: 'One'})} role="tab">One</a>
            </li>
            <li className={"tabProperties" + this.getActiveSubTab('Two')}>
              <a onClick={() => this.setState({subtab: 'Two'})} role="tab">Two</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div className="tab-content">
          {this.getContent()}
        </div>
     </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<TodoApp />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-ui-bootstrap/0.5pre/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

When the active tabs are "X" and "One", I expect the text field to load the default "1. Ex" string and then when I change tabs to "Y" and "One", I expect the text field to load "2. Why" string. However, the text field doesn't change unless I also change to "Two" tab, which unloads the `<textarea>` element, and then change back to the "One" tab. How should I handle the requirements of a default value, which is represented via `props`, and the automatic update necessitating `onChange` handler?

If I use `value` to set the text of the text field, it will update the text on state change but it removes the ability for the user to alter the text field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `value` instead of `defaultValue` in your textarea field.
The reason: The `defaultValue` only specifies the value when the input is initially created: so said, no updates are possible.

Comment: If I use value to set the text of the text field, it will update the text on state change but it removes the ability for the user to alter the text field.

Comment: Indeed you need to handle any change in the textarea field via updating your text state in your onChange event handler. (So, it does not work with your static props approach - if you get the text value via props, you need to change it in the parent - or you create own text states that are used. If the text states are empty, you fall back to your props value.)